# How can there be a directory named `~`?

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, quoting, rm

I was trying to test out this buggy/new tool to see how it works, and it prompted me to choose a directory to use for stuff I am doing. From the directory `~/Code/indep`, I typed in `~/Code/indep/tarbell`. (Stupid, I could have just typed 'tarbell', but whatever.) It prompted me to create it because it didn't exist, I said yes. When I inspected the contents of this directory, here is what I see:

```
brian@navis:~/Code/indep$ ls
~ project1 project2 project3 ...
```

I thought "oh, weird, it created a symlink to ~". However:

```
brian@navis:~/Code/indep$ file ./~
./~: directory
```

`file` thinks it's a directory.

```
brian@navis:~/Code/indep$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 brian brian 4096 Nov  8 16:50 ~
drwxr-xr-x 8 brian brian 4096 Oct 14 18:42 project1
drwxr-xr-x 3 brian brian 4096 Sep 10 21:15 project2
drwxr-xr-x 5 brian brian 4096 Oct 14 19:33 project3
...
```

And so does `ls -l`.

I thought, "oh, ... is it a hard link? I've never really used those." But I tried to reproduce, and it's impossible to create a hard link to a directory. So... I guess I've narrowed this down to things I don't understand. Did I mount my home directory in this other directory somehow?

My main goal at this point is to remove the reference to my home directory in this folder (`rm` doesn't seem like the answer), but I'm also curious to know what's going on.

EDIT:

In retrospect, I understand exactly what happened. As was answered below, the program created a directory called "`~`" inside my current directory. The only really obfuscating fact about this is that I wasn't consistent with how I was actually viewing what the directory was. Sometimes I referred to it as  "`~`" and sometimes as "`./~`". It's only if you do the latter that you can actually see what's going on, but until I understood this, I was conflating what I was seeing from using the absolute path of "`~`" to to what was in fact a local directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a directory whose name is "~". Your shell will attempt to expand "~" if it's the first character of an argument, so you have to take special measures.

```
$ mkdir ./~
$ file ./~
./~: directory
$ rm -ri ./~
rm: remove directory ‘./~’? y
```

Comment: I should be much more patient.

Comment: I didn't read through your proposed way of deleting the directory, and removed my home directory as soon as I read the first line and saw that you were right.